# Содержимого формы нет в письме

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Настроил скрипт отправки формы, письмо доходит, но без данных формы.
Форма:

```
  <form style="display: inline;">
 <input class="form" type="number" name="user_phone" placeholder="+7 (ххх) ххх хх хх" required>
  <button type="submit" class="do-submit">Отправить</button>
 </form>
```

Обработчик:

```
require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';


$phone = $_POST['user_phone'];


//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';                                                                                           // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'vac9p@mail.ru'; // 
$mail->Password = ''; // письма
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465; // TCP port to connect to / этот порт может отличаться у других провайдеров

$mail->setFrom('vac9p@mail.ru'); // 
$mail->addAddress('dandelion.digital@mail.ru');     // Кому будет уходить письмо 
//$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Заявка с тестового сайта';
$mail->Body    = ''.$phone;
$mail->AltBody = '';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
}
?>
```

JQ:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("form").submit(function (e) {
           sendForm(e);
           return false;
      });
 });
 function sendForm (e) {
      var formNm = $(e);
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'mail.php',
           data: formNm.serialize(),
           success: function (data) {
                // Вывод текста результата отправки
                $(formNm).html(data);
           },
           error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
                // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
                $(formNm).html(error);
           }
      });
 }
```

Comment: Если честно, то я не понимаю зачем писать подобную отправку формы на сервер? Если при нажатии на `submit` она и так улетит? Пароли и адресатов лучше не указывать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("form").submit(function (e) {
    sendForm(this); // !!! передавайте элемент формы в функцию sendForm
    return false;
  });
});

function sendForm(form) {
  var formNm = $(form);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'mail.php',
    data: formNm.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
      // Вывод текста результата отправки
      formNm.html(data);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, text, error) {
      // Вывод текста ошибки отправки
      formNm.html(error);
    }
  });
}
```